# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Tags: vb.net

I do have the below snippet of code to set the ComboBox value which is throwing an exception, even though the correct values are being populated in the comboBox(s)!

```
Dim DOB As Date

DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateOfBirth.Text)

Console.WriteLine((DOB.Month).ToString)
Console.WriteLine((DOB.Day).ToString)
Console.WriteLine((DOB.Year).ToString)

cmbMonth.SelectedIndex = cmbMonth.FindString(DOB.Month.ToString)
cmbDay.SelectedIndex = cmbDay.FindString(DOB.Day.ToString)
cmbYear.SelectedIndex = cmbYear.FindString(DOB.Year.ToString)
```

OutPut Console:

```
9
8
1993
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
```

Comment: SelectedIndex is an int.  Are you sure you’re not meaning selecteditem?

Comment: .FinsString returns and int. Which is the index of the value found!. I could try and just simplify it to set the selected item instead of doing FindString... However, the exception being thrown is bugging me. Not sure why!

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit switched on? Can you step through the code with the debugger and see which line throws the exception? Can you switch on Break on all exceptions and see where it throws?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `DateTimePicker` and get rid of all those controls and that code?

Comment: I am reading from a database as text, then populating my comboBoxs (Month, Day, Year) .... Do you have Option Explicit switched on? " Not sure what you mean?"  When I have a breakpoint on the line "cmbMonth.SelectedIndex = cm month.FindString(DOB.Month.ToString)" and step through the code no exception is thrown.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown then? Maybe the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler? Keep on debugging your code, to see what happens after those lines are executed.

Comment: Add this to the top of your class: 'Option Explicit On'. Also, click Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings and set all the values on and then run again and see where it breaks.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Thank you very much for the tip. Enabling all Exception Settings has pointed me to the exact line which was thrown the exception due to Invalid Casting from String to Double. Please add it as an answer, this tip will help many. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by @Andrew Mortimer

Enable all Exception Setting to catch all exceptions while debugging

Debug -> Windows -> Exceptions Settings

[image]